# Why do we use length - 1?

Tags: python, for-loop

> Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where they contain the same length 2 substring. So "xxcaazz" and "xxbaaz" yields 3, since the "xx", "aa", and "az" substrings appear in the same place in both strings.
>
> Solution:
>
> ```
> def string_match(a, b):
>     # Figure which string is shorter.
>     shorter = min(len(a), len(b))
>     count = 0
>   
>     # Loop i over every substring starting spot.
>     # Use length-1 here, so can use char str[i+1] in the loop
>     for i in range(shorter-1):
>         a_sub = a[i:i+2]
>         b_sub = b[i:i+2]
>         if a_sub == b_sub:
>            count = count + 1
>
>     return count
> ```

Was doing some practice from [online sources](https://codingbat.com/prob/p182414). What I don't understand is the comment where it mentions use length -1. Why do we do that?

Comment: Try removing the `-1` and see what happens.  (If it's not obvious what's happening, print `a_sub` and `b_sub` -- they should always be 2-character strings.  Are they?)

Comment: The post contains the answer... "Use length-1 here, so can use char str[i+1] in the loop". This is to avoid out of range access...

Comment: yes it does contain the answer because my question is a theory based not the actual code needed.

Answer (score 1):

Image that like sliding window:

```
__----
^^
this is window, and the rest of it is space where this window can slide.
Now, you want to slide to the end of that space.

1. iteration
-__---
-^^---
2. iteration
--__--
--^^--
3. iteration
---__-
---^^-
4. iteration
----__
----^^
```

The window reached the end. But look at that where is starting of that windows. The window length is 2, so starting of the window is at the second position from the right. That is why you wrote on that loop `range(shorter-1)`.
If you wrote `range(shorter)` window will slide out of that space.